# Using Twig to generate Markdown, how to indent blocks in twig?

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, twig, indentation

I have very few hours of use with Twig so I probably missed an important tip; please forgive me if this is a trivial question.

I'm using Twig with PHP for the generation of markdown files.

My twig file contains one or more `{% for %}...{% endfor %}` block and inside a for-loop, a few `{% if %}...{% endif %}` and ... I can't make any indentation in my Twig otherwise the spaces are also present in my output.

A very stupid example: https://twigfiddle.com/fb6nzq (use the `Show raw result` to make sure to see the spaces before the word `true`).

If I don't indent my `{% if %}...{% endif %}`, I got the correct result (https://twigfiddle.com/fb6nzq/2) but I don't have anymore indentation of blocks in my template.

In my real world twig file, I can have multiple `{% endif %}` like below and it becomes unreadable.

```
{% for (variable) %}
{% if (condition) %}
{% if (condition) %}
{% if (condition) %}
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor%}
```

So ... do you know if there is a wonderful trick to keep an indentation in your code but without having an impact on the output?

Desired twig template:

```
{% for (variable) %}
   {% if (condition) %}
      {% if (condition) %}
         {% if (condition) %}
         {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor%}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dash `-` on any opening or closing twig expression where:

- a dash on the closing expression would do a trim on the left.
  `{% if true -%}`
- a dash on the opening expression would do a trim on the right
  `{%- if true %}`
- a dash on the both the opening and closing expression would do a trim on the both sides
  `{%- if true -%}`

***Mind that:*** this is acting as a PHP trim, so that means that it will also trim your line feeds!

Here is an example:

```
{% for i in 1..5 %}
   {% if true %}
      {% if true %}
         {%- if  true %}   
foo
         {%- endif %}
      {%- endif %}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

That renders:

```
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
```

*This is testable here: https://twigfiddle.com/1awhzk*

***Also note:*** that there is a [`spaceless` tag](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/spaceless.html) to achieve those kind of things.

Comment: Many, many thanks Benoit! Will try this next week at work but as far I see / understand, that's exactly answer to my need.

Comment: I've play a little and discovered that the spaceless tag is deprecated and even removed with Twig 3 (*The spaceless tag in "main.twig" at line 1 is deprecated since Twig 2.7, use the "spaceless" filter with the "apply" tag instead.*), so don't use it. (we can see this here : https://twigfiddle.com/1awhzk)